# What does the ../../ mean when returning symbolic links?

Tags: linux, hyperlink, openstack, zfs

A symbolic link created by zfs is returning as ../../zd0, tested through multiple ways to check. Not sure why the result is not /dev/zd0 as that is the actual link as far as I am aware.

```
admin@r2-compute1:~$ ls -l /dev/zvol/cpool/cinder-volumes
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jun 25 09:53 /dev/zvol/cpool/cinder-volumes -> ../../zd0

admin@r2-compute1:~$ stat /dev/zvol/cpool/cinder-volumes
  File: /dev/zvol/cpool/cinder-volumes -> ../../zd0
  Size: 9           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 640         Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-06-25 10:07:28.610707769 -0700
Modify: 2020-06-25 09:53:52.174435310 -0700
Change: 2020-06-25 09:53:52.174435310 -0700
 Birth: -

admin@r2-compute1:~$ file /dev/zvol/cpool/cinder-volumes
/dev/zvol/cpool/cinder-volumes: symbolic link to ../../zd0
```

I am working with openstack and zfs and am wondering why the symbolic link returns "../../zd0" instead of "dev/zd0". I am not sure what the ../../ means and understanding would assist in my openstack implementation understanding. First time posting and Google and SymbolHound did not produce any results in regards to the meaning behind ../../
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably while creating the soft links **../../zd0** was adopted instead of the full path **/dev/zd0** (or whatever the path was supposed to be given).

If absolutely necessary, you may try to unlink this first and recreate the link by providing FULL-PATH to the DEVICE/FILE.

NOTE: ***Try this with caution and ensure the paths are correct, this is just the symbolic code to help you correct the error***:

```
unlink /dev/zvol/cpool/cinder-volumes
ln -s /dev/zvol/cpool/cinder-volumes /dev/zd0
```

Comment: The question starts with "A symbolic link created by zfs ...".  Without knowing why zfs uses a relative link such as `../../zd0`, changing the link to an absolute link such as `/dev/zd0` may very well break something.  And it may not break for a long time.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHenle, I understand that and I've updated the approach/language in my answer. A warning against such forceful-modifications was already there in my answer but a seeker can always try&work, if insist to find an answer.

BrotherBerry did this help?

Comment: Somewhat @AmitVerma. I think my confusion is stemming from the literal "../../" portion. I just am not sure what parent directories the two ".." portions are referencing, and I am not sure how that reference is still relevant to the link.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Do you know what parent directories the two ".." portions are referencing? I am not sure how that reference is still relevant to the link.